# Regex to match math equations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, math, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to build a derivative calculator, so I'm breaking the equation into components and matching each piece to determine the rule to apply, but I'm completely new to regular expressions.

Right now, I'm trying to match x^n and Ax^nx where A and n are constants. This is my equation: `x{0,}^[0-9]{0,}` but when I run the code below and input something like `asdf`, `5`, and `x^3`, they all return as matches when only `x^3` should return. Is there a problem  in the equation or in the way I'm applying it below?

```
NSRegularExpression* regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern: @"x{0,}^[0-9]{0,}" options: NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error: nil];

if ([regex numberOfMatchesInString: equation options: NSMatchingHitEnd range: [equation rangeOfString: equation]] > 0)
{
    NSLog(@"Match x^n");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Not x^n");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^` depicts the start of the string so it should be escaped like `\^`

Your `regex` should be

`@"\d*x\\^\d*"`

`\d` represents a digit..

`*` means match 0 to many `\d`

Comment: Almost perfect. For some reason, it's not understanding \d so x^3 would work, but 3x^3 won't. I replaced \d* with [0-9]* and it works. Danks